# Importing custom Java enum in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums

I'm trying one of my first Java projects in Intellij, and am trying to define an enum we will call ShadowField.  In the src folder I have my UI.java, and my ShadowField enum file.  However, if I try to reference any of the enum values, it does not recognize the symbol.  I've tried to put an include statement at the top of the file, but it does not recognize that symbol either.  How do I reference this enum?  Does Intellij have a different way of doing this?

For reference, this is the entirety of the enum file:

```
public enum ShadowField {
   COMBAT, MAGIC, HACKING
}
```

Comment: Your classpath for the project is not set correctly.

Comment: Can you post UI.java too?

Comment: Please post your entire project hierarchy, and please also post your UI.java.

Comment: Well, somehow it's now recognizing the enum, but when I try to print out the values it's for some reason giving me the string instead of an int value.

Here is UI.java:

     `public class UI {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
     UI ui = new UI();


    }

    public UI () {
        System.out.println ( "Test" );
        System.out.println(ShadowField.MAGIC);
        System.out.println(ShadowField.COMBAT.equals(0));
    }

}`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, not sure how to make it look better.  The output I get from those print statements are "Test", "MAGIC", and "false" respectively.  I feel like it should be "Test", "1", and "true".

Comment: Printing enums invokes toString(), which prints the enum name. If you wanted it to print the index, you would need to write that indexing into your enum yourself.

Answer (score 0):

here's how to do what you want to do, via the `.ordinal()` method (which returns an `int` for any enum).

```
public UI() {
    System.out.println("Test");
    System.out.println(ShadowField.MAGIC.ordinal());
    System.out.println(ShadowField.COMBAT.ordinal() == 0);
}
```

But, may I suggest that you avoid using the `.ordinal()` for enums? Ask yourself what will happen to your code if an enum gets added at the left?

```
public enum ShadowField {
   AWESOME, COMBAT, MAGIC, HACKING
}
```

For example, this would break:

```
    if (myVar.ordinal() == 1) { ... }
```

Wheres this would not

```
    if (myVar == ShadowMagic.MAGIC) { ... }
```

Good luck and have fun onwards :)